# How to avoid using data access layer in presentation layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ninject

I have a data layer which uses Sqlite for CRUD operation, so in my Sqlite Class I have to pass path of a DB, to do that I have interface `IConnectionProvider` in Data Layer as below:

```
public interface IConnectionProvider
 {
        string DbPath { get; }
 }
```

SqliteDb.cs

```
public class SQLiteDb : DbContext, IDbContext
    {
        internal const string DefaultDatabaseName = "My.db";

        private string connectionString = null;

        public SQLiteDb(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionProvider.DbPath;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

My project architecture is as below:

```
 Data Layer -> View Model -> Presentation Layer
```

I want to avoid using Data Layer directly into Presentation layer, but to pass DBPath I have to add reference of it.

Below is the implementation of `IConnectionProvider` in my presentation layer:

```
public class SqlConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider
    {
        public string dbPath = string.Empty;
        public string DbPath
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath))
                {
                    dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MyDb.sqlite");
                }

                return dbPath;
            }
        }
  }
```

Is there any way I can avoid using DataLayer directly into Presentation Layer? I thought of creating wrapper in VM but I don't think that it would be a good Idea as will create more dependencies.

Comment: Sure, inject it and program to the data layer interface? It's not clear what you're asking other than to simply say - "don't do what you're doing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to do this is to use the Repository Pattern. Define an Interface in the ViewModel Layer and implement it in the DataLayer. Then the ViewModel does not know anything about the DataLayer. Then instantiate the Repository with the ConnectionProvider in your main class via Dependency Injection. Also the dbContext has to move to the DataLayer and you should use it in the Repository. I would recommend putting the connection string in a config file and use this in the DL. The classes should look something like this

```
namespace ViewModel;
interface IDatabaseRepository {
   DataObject LoadData()
}

namespace DataLayer;
class DataRepository {
   public DataRepository(DbContext context) {
      this.context = context;
   }

   public DataObject LoadData() {
      //load data from DB using dbContext
   }
}

namespace ViewModel;
class ViewModel {
   public ViewModel(IDataRepository repository) {
      this.repository = repository;
   }

   // use the repository inside this class to acces data
}
```

Also look up Dependency Inversion Principle as this helps with decoupling things like that.

Comment: Thanks, but I have reference of DL in VM, and VM in PL and I have to provide path from PL instead of VM. So the approach you mentioned will not work in my case. Correct me if am missing something.

Comment: The Presentationlayer should know nothing about the ConnectionProvider, as this is something that belongs to the DB Layer. This might be the only problem you are having. I usually have a extra project for the DependencyInjection, that initializes everything and knows every project. I use to call this Project "Host". Is your entry point in the PL? This should not be there, as this would require the PL to know too much.

Comment: You are right, but Path for DB can only be generated from PL as DL and VM don't have API's to get the Application Path. Basically my DL  and VM is .Net Standard 2.0 and PL is UWP App. So From UWP App I need o pass DBPath to Data layer.

Comment: I would rather have the hard coded string in the DL or read it from a config file than being generated in the PL. But you can pass the string from the PL down to the database without referencing the DL in PL. How do you generate this string in the PL? I would not know a reason that UWP has to know anything from the database. If you generate the DB from the UWP project, do it in the viewmodel via another Repository and Interface aswell. The UI should only know the string to the location maybe, but not the classes that use that string.

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer, you can see that how I am Generating DbPath in PL and how it's been used in DL in SQliteDb.cs. But right now I am using 'IConnectionProvider' which is part of DL in PL and I want to avoid using that.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see the problem ;) You should never have the dbContext in your PL in the first place. This is totally a DB class, as it says in the name. You have to put this in the DL or otherwise you have no architecture at all. If the dbContext is in your PL you can put everything in one project, as there is no layer whatsoever. Trust me on this one, a PL never has to know anything about a dbContext class. And it should not, because its responsibility is to present things to the user. Does a db Context present something? No, so no PL. Does a dbContext store data? Yes, so it goes into the DL.

Comment: I guess you are still missing my point, DBContext is still part of my DL and also IConnectionProvider, but as I need to get DB path from PL I am implementing IConnectionProvider in PL, and that's what I want to avoid at first.

Comment: Yes, than you just should not do that. Make a DTO that transfers the string down to the Provider through the viewmodel and initialize the db in a factory in the DL Layer. I really do not see why you should not be able to do that. After all you just want a string that you retrieve from the user in the db layer, right? Or is the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` making you use a uwp library? Then change this also to just a string in the DBlayer and use a DTO to get it there.

Comment: And by the way, you do not need the whole applicationpath. The relative path is enough in uwp as the folder where the app is located in has all the right to acces the filesystem. You just have to deploy the DB there and use it like "mydb.sqllite" without the whole path. And this is something you can make in the DL only. Or do you want the user to select the DB that they are using, that is residing somewhere on the harddrive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172038/discussion-between-dishant-and-simons0n).

Comment: @Dishant you usually mark it as an answer when your problem is solved to show to others that this actually helped you. You can do both :)